# Flip letters of a string - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Simple coding assignment: Take text from a textbox and flip it so it's backwords:

i.e. Hello My Name Is David would be "divad si eman ym olleh" ( The program doesn't have to match case, just the letters)

This is something I found, do you have any other methods?

```
Dim str As String = Textbox1.Text
Dim arr As New List(Of Char)
arr.AddRange(str.ToCharArray)
arr.Reverse()

For Each l As Char In arr
lblOne.Text &= l
Next
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in one line with using the **[`StrReverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ycf85wx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)** function (in Microsoft.VisualBasic).

```
Dim myText As String = "My Name is Dave"
Dim revText As String = StrReverse(myText)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick one liner.

```
lblOne.Text = String.Join("", "divad si eman ym olleh".Reverse())
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.VisualBasic

```
Dim myText As String = My Name is  abc
Dim revText As String = StrReverse(myText)
```

Output:  "cba si eman ym"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Join` instead of looping through each character and concatenating:

```
lblOne.Text = String.Join("", arr)
```

Comment: Even though I selected a different answer, could you explain what string.join does? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a `function` that accepts string an returns a reversed string.

```
Function Reverse(ByVal value As String) As String
    Dim arr() As Char = value.ToCharArray()
    Array.Reverse(arr)
    Return New String(arr)
End Function
```

and try using it like this,

```
lblOne.Text  = Reverse(Textbox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar way but with fewer number of lines.

```
Dim Original_Text As String = "Hello My Name is Ahmad"
Dim Reversed_Text As String = ""

For i = Original_Text.Length To 1 Step -1
    Reversed_Text &= Original_Text.Substring(i, 1)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to reverse a string is :

```
Dim s As String = "1234ab cdefgh"
MessageBox.Show(s.AsEnumerable.Reverse.ToArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First Create a textbox, it will be TextBox1
2. then create a button and name it Reverse
3. then Create a label, it will be Label1
4. Now double click on Reverse Button (Go to Button Click Event)
5. and type following code.
6. and run software And type your string in textbox and click on reverse button.

   ```
   Dim MainText As String = TextBox1.Text
   Dim revText As String = StrReverse(MainText)
   Label1.Text = revText
   ```